# WSO2 EMM install android application .apk

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I had successfully install the WSO2 agent to my device and add it.
I had also add android app on the emm server and publish it.
Now, i want to install the android app on my smartphone so i followed the steps described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Installing+and+Reinstalling+Mobile+Apps) 
When i clicked  on install button and select my device, a popin opens and close quicly "Applications is previsioned to the device" but nothing is installed on the divice.

Comment: Have you properly enrolled your device with the EMM?

Comment: Can we see Android logcat logs on this?